# Automatically closing #ifdef block when editing C code

Tags: c-mode, skeleton

When editing LaTeX code, the command `latex-close-block` inserts an `\end{..}` that matches the last unclosed `\begin{..}`. Very handy!

Is there a similar command in `c-mode` that would close a pending `#ifdef`? Ideally, I would close

```
#ifdef __A_COND__
```

with a nicely commented `#endif`, like in

```
#endif /* __A_COND__ */
```

If such a command does not exist, how would you program it? From scratch or using `skeleton.el`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using this yasnippet:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: ifndef
# key: ifndef
# --
#ifndef ${1:`(upcase (file-name-nondirectory (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-file-name))))`_HH_}
#define $1

$0
#endif
```

You can quickly customize it to do what you want.

### In case you're not using yasnippet yet

Here's my personal config (you can take the parts that you like):

```
(use-package yasnippet
    :diminish yas-minor-mode
    :init
    (progn
      (setq yas-fallback-behavior 'return-nil)
      (setq yas-triggers-in-field t)
      (setq yas-verbosity 0)
      ;; I'm using my own snippets, turn bundled snippets off
      ;; (setq yas-snippet-dirs (list (concat emacs.d "snippets/")))
      (define-key yas-minor-mode-map [(tab)] nil)
      (define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "TAB") nil)
      (yas-global-mode)))

;; (package-install 'auto-yasnippet)
(global-set-key "\C-o" 'aya-open-line)
```

It needs `auto-yasnippet` (it's in MELPA, `yasnippet` is a dependency).

So now <kbd>C-o</kbd> will try in order to:

- expand abbrev
- expand yasnippet or move to the next yasnippet field if already expanding
- open line

Comment: THANKS!!! This looks great (based on the number of upvotes) so I am eager to try it. But 1st I must learn about yasnippets and understand what you mean. Let me read [this page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Yasnippet) and digest its contents. Aside: I'm always surprised by how much stuff has been added to Emacs since 1984 when I first used it.

Comment: I've added my yasnippet config. It can be a start if you want a custom yasnippet config.

Answer (score 2):

[`smartparens`](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens) (and some other "auto pair" packages) allows you to do something similar:

```
(sp-pair "#ifdef" "#endif")
```

This won't easily get you that ending comment like a snippet engine can (I believe it's possible with `smartparens`, though), but it answers your title so I thought it was close enough to warrant an answer.